# Disable IE shortcut keys in the WebBrowser controls

Tags: wpf

I am using a WPF WebBrowser control to host a Silverlight App.  The Silverlight App has some shortcut keys enabled, however, they conflict with the shortcut keys from Internet Explorer (Eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).  Also there are some undesired effects from other shortcut key combinations, eg. I don't want users to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to open a new window, etc..

Is there a way to disable the shortcut keys for the web browser control?

Note: I have already tried using the InputBindings property on the web browser control and doing something like this:

```
KeyBinding Command="NotACommand" Key="S"
```

This does not work though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the WinForms WebBrowser control and set the [WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.webbrowsershortcutsenabled) to false.

Comment: This belongs to System.Windows.Forms, but the tag in question says it's a WPF app.

Comment: I know they were using a WPF app. That doesn't prevent you from using WinForms controls in it and since the WPF browser is just a thin wrapper around the ActiveX object it's not much different then using a WindowsFormsHost and have a WF WebBrowser in there. Both are HwndHost derived and will have many of the same shortcomings - e.g. airspace issues - but at least the WF one has a setting that might help them get closer to what they want.